# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range

Tags: postgresql, scala, scala-cats, doobie

The exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
```

... only occurs if a string interpolation is added to the query below, for example:

```
[...]('SRID=4326;Point(${geoPoint.longitude} ${geoPoint.latitude})'), location)[...]
```

If the variables are removed (values hardcoded), it works just fine:

```
def fetchBy(geoPoint: GeoPoint, radius: Int): Query0[Merchant] = {
  sql"""SELECT data->>'name' AS name, data->>'address' AS address, data->>'postCode' AS postCode, st_distance(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;Point(-0.233226 51.5060804)'), location) AS distance FROM merchant WHERE ST_DWithin(location, ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;Point(-0.233226 51.5060804)'), 1000) ORDER BY distance;"""
  .query[Merchant]
}
```

---

### My setup

Postgres GIS Schema:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE TABLE merchant (
  id varchar NOT NULL,
  location geography,
  data jsonb
);
```

The case class to decode the query result to:

```
final case class Merchant(name: String, address: Option[Address] = None, postCode: String, distance: Option[String] = None)
object Merchant {
  implicit val merchantEncoder: Encoder[Merchant]       = deriveEncoder[Merchant]
  implicit val merchantDecoder: Decoder[Merchant]       = deriveDecoder[Merchant]
  implicit val decoder: EntityDecoder[IO, Merchant]     = jsonOf[IO, Merchant]
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setBinaryParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:131)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindBytes(PgPreparedStatement.java:1005)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setDouble(PgPreparedStatement.java:323)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setDouble(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at doobie.util.meta.MetaInstances.$anonfun$DoubleMeta$2(meta.scala:197)
    at doobie.util.meta.MetaInstances.$anonfun$DoubleMeta$2$adapted(meta.scala:197)
    at doobie.util.Put.unsafeSetNonNullable(put.scala:40)
    at doobie.util.fragment$Fragment.$anonfun$write$5(fragment.scala:55)
    at doobie.util.fragment$Fragment.$anonfun$write$5$adapted(fragment.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    at doobie.util.fragment$Fragment.$anonfun$write$4(fragment.scala:53)
    at doobie.util.fragment$Fragment.$anonfun$write$4$adapted(fragment.scala:51)
    at doobie.util.Write.$anonfun$set$1(write.scala:26)
    at doobie.util.Write.$anonfun$set$1$adapted(write.scala:26)
    at doobie.free.KleisliInterpreter.$anonfun$primitive$2(kleisliinterpreter.scala:112)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:87)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.startCancelable(IORunLoop.scala:41)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.run(IOBracket.scala:88)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.cats$effect$internals$Trampoline$$immediateLoop(Trampoline.scala:67)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.startLoop(Trampoline.scala:35)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.super$startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:89)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.$anonfun$startLoop$1(TrampolineEC.scala:89)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:85)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:89)
    at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.execute(Trampoline.scala:43)
    at cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC.execute(TrampolineEC.scala:42)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:69)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:49)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:139)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.signal(IORunLoop.scala:359)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:380)
    at cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:323)
    at cats.effect.internals.IOShift$Tick.run(IOShift.scala:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You don't show the SQL statement.

Comment: The SQL is inside the fetchBy method (3rd snippet from top down). It blows up if the lat/long values are replaced by variables as on the 2nd snippet from top down.